# Not Update original list

Tags: c#

How to update the original list as I see cities list is not getting updated.

I have list of objects which I pass cities to function as

```
AssignSchduleAndReschdule(schduleMaster.Schdules[0].Citiesforwardjounny, cityIDfrom,hour)
```

An `AssignSchduleAndReschdule` function I change the `CitySchduletime` values but it's getting reflected in original object.

```
private void AssignSchduleAndReschdule(...........)
{
    cityseq = cities.Where(item => item.CityId == cityIDto).FirstOrDefault().Sequence;
    foreach (var city in cities.Where(item => item.Sequence <= cityseq).Reverse())
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            SchduleTime schdule = city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault();
            if (schdule == null)
                return;
            previous = schdule.Schduletimestart;
            first = true;
         }
         else
         {
            DateTimeOffset ts = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(previous).AddHours(-defaultgap);
            int eta = 3800;
            long endtime = ts.AddSeconds(-eta).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            previous = ts.AddSeconds(-eta).AddHours(-1).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            SchduleTime schduleTime = city.CitySchduletime.Where(item => item.Schduletimestart == hour).FirstOrDefault();
            if (schduleTime != null)
            {
               if (previous > DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds())
               {
                   schduleTime.Schduletimestop = endtime;
                   schduleTime.Schduletimestart = previous;
               }
               else
               {
                   city.CitySchduletime.Remove(schduleTime);
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SchduleTime` is a class or a struct?

Comment: Does the `.Reverse` a new object instead of returning the same? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,906

Comment: SchduleTime  is a class